# matching values in dataframe to other in group_by

Tags: r

I am working with a dataset in R and I have a dataframe with "name, latitude, longitude, and count". If I group_by name I get 3 rows if I group_by longitude I get 6 rows because the longitudes do not match. This is incorrect they should be one of the two.

```
name <- c("loc_1", "loc_1", "loc_2", "loc_2", "loc_3", "loc_3")
latitude <- c(44.359, 44.359, 44.479, 44.479, 43.522, 43.522)
longitude <- c(-89.839, -89.837, -88.137, -88.130, -89.774, -89.771)
total <- c(9, 6506, 6506, 5, 12966, 351)
t1 <- data.frame(name, latitude, longitude, total)


    name  latitude longitude  total
1  loc_1   44.359   -89.839   9
2  loc_1   44.359   -89.837   6506
3  loc_2   44.479   -88.137   6002
4  loc_2   44.479   -88.130   5
5  loc_3   43.522   -89.774   12966
6  loc_3   43.522   -89.771   351
```

I need to change one of the longitudes to match the other they are close together so I am not concerned. I don't have much to add to this, short of changing them all one at a time which would take forever with a large dataset.

```
    name  latitude longitude  total
1  loc_1   44.359   -89.837   6515
2  loc_2   44.479   -88.137   6007
3  loc_3   43.522   -89.774   13,317
```

The totals are now correct for each location and it can be mapped with one point per location.

Comment: You want to group by name and latitude?

Comment: This is a subset of a bigger dataset the group_by is for testing to find errors like this. I just want 3 locations each with a lat, lon, and total.

Comment: Why do you also group by longitude? Does not every location have approximately the same longitude or latitude?

Comment: Yes, very close but I need them to be the same. It is a reading from a sensor and I guess the sensor is returning bad longitude for some minutes. This data will be mapped at some point and I only wont one point for each location with a total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your answer to my comment, you could try this:

```
library(dplyr)
t1 %>% group_by(name) %>% 
  summarise(latitude = as.numeric(names(sort(table(latitude), decreasing = TRUE)))[1],
            longitude = as.numeric(names(sort(table(longitude), decreasing = TRUE)))[1],
            total = sum(total))
```

It picks the latitude and longitude that occurs most often and sums the total. Maybe you need to change `sum(total)` to `n()` if you havent already counted some of them...

Comment: Thank you Tino that is what I was looking for.